# What are the default values for lintOptions?

Tags: android, build.gradle, android-lint

Where can the default values for `lintOptions` be found?

I have found the documentation [here](http://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.LintOptions.html#N1138F) but I cannot find what these values are by default

Answer (score 1):

I don't know a documentation with all default values.

However you can check the source code used in 1.5 [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/+/studio-1.5/build-system/gradle-core/src/main/groovy/com/android/build/gradle/internal/dsl/LintOptions.java?autodive=0%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F):

```
/**
 * DSL object for configuring lint options.
 */
public class LintOptions implements com.android.builder.model.LintOptions, Serializable {
    public static final String STDOUT = "stdout";
    public static final String STDERR = "stderr";
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @NonNull
    private Set<String> disable = Sets.newHashSet();
    @NonNull
    private Set<String> enable = Sets.newHashSet();
    @Nullable
    private Set<String> check = Sets.newHashSet();
    private boolean abortOnError = true;
    private boolean absolutePaths = true;
    private boolean noLines;
    private boolean quiet;
    private boolean checkAllWarnings;
    private boolean ignoreWarnings;
    private boolean warningsAsErrors;
    private boolean showAll;
    private boolean checkReleaseBuilds = true;
    private boolean explainIssues = true;
    @Nullable
    private File lintConfig;
    private boolean textReport;
    @Nullable
    private File textOutput;
    private boolean htmlReport = true;
    @Nullable
    private File htmlOutput;
    private boolean xmlReport = true;
    @Nullable
    private File xmlOutput;

  //..

}
```